# Why is my SwiftUI List not updating with the correct User object after the first HTTP request?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `List` that iterates an array of class instances named `User` and displays a `View` with properties of each element. The view has a text displaying the `countReviews` property of concrete `User` class instance. Class instances are passed to the list element view as a `State` variable:

```
var users = [User]()

List {
    ForEach(users) { user in
        ReviewView(userVar: user)
    }
}
```

`Review` struct:

```
struct ReviewView: View {
    @State var userVar: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(userVar.countReviews))
            .task {
                await updateCount()
            }
    }

    func updateCount() async {
        // HTTP request that returns a User object from server
        // Once response received and decoded with decoder:
        userVar = response.user
    }
}
```

`User` class:

```
class User: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var countReviews: Int?
}
```

The problem is, when the `updateCount()` function is called for the first time, the `userVar` is being replaced with the new `User` class instance. But when it's called for the second time, the `userVar` object inherits an instance from `users` variable and is not being updated anymore.

Comment: `@State` is (mostly) for value types. Unless there's a compelling reason to do otherwise, you should make your model a `struct`

Comment: You need to read the **very basics** of `SwiftUI`, see for example: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/
 Also have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I've read the very basics of SwiftUI, including the course you mentioned, however, thanks for the link to managing model data

Comment: @jnpdx thank you! I think, you gave a great hint. I declared User as class, since want it to be mutable. But I also think, StateObject would be a better fit

Comment: You can mutate a struct that is stored in State or in a Published property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could change the state to `countReviews: Int?` and set it in the task.
2. Change User to a struct. When a struct is @State it becomes mutable and you can use mutating func for logic. Any change to a property of a struct is detected as a change to the state.

Also if you use:

```
Text(userVar.countReviews, format: .number)
```

You'll benefit from auto reformatting of the `UILabel` text if the user changes their region/language.